Should IHttpContextAccessor be avoided? Getting user information into a DI service
There is a lot of information about using IHttpContextAccessor to inject user information in a DI service. However, there is a warning on this interface that suggests it should be used with caution.

This interface should be used with caution. It relies on AsyncLocal which can have a negative performance impact on async calls. It also creates a dependency on "ambient state" which can make testing more difficult.

What I think someone is about to tell me is that injecting user information is a code smell and I should bite the bullet and pass it down from the controller? Or can I do something in middleware instead?
Update:
public class CurrentUserNameProvider : ICurrentUserNameProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CurrentUserNameProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get name of current user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetCurrentUserName()
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
        return user.Identity.Name;
    }
}

Many thanks,
James

Show us this service of yours first.

With the current implementation of .NET (Core), there are a few things to take into consideration, concerning the use of AsyncLocal, which is the mechanism behind the default IHttpContextAccessor implementation:

There could be a negative performance impact, as the documentation states, although I found this to be especially relevant in getting the requests per second up in benchmarks, rather than that it has any noticeable impact on real-world applications that run any I/O during a request.
Iterating over an IAsyncEnumerable (by you or a third-party library that you call) clears the state of AsyncLocal, causing the IHttpContextAccessor to lose its reference to the current HttpContext object. I've been tracking this issue for the last three years. I, and many others, have been urging Microsoft to fix this but, up until now, Microsoft has no fix available. Not even a CaptureExecutionContextOnAsyncEnumeration=true configuration switch, or if they like CaptureExecutionContextOnAsyncEnumerationAndYesIUnderstandTheImpact=true.

Note that while the documentation does state the negative performance impact, it actually lacks to warn about the far more important issue of correctness.
Unfortunately, the documentation also states:

It also creates a dependency on "ambient state" which can make testing more difficult.

This statement, however, is false IMO. Although the HttpContextAccessor implementation depends on AsyncLocal and thus "ambient state," classes depend on the IHttpContextAccessor abstraction, and this abstraction can be replaced (which is the promise of DI), which doesn't limit testing in any meaningful way. I'm unsure how this statement leaked into the documentation. I suspect that this originates from the opinion of one of .NET's lead architects. I had a discussion with that architect back in 2017 about the topic of ambient state and testability. In that discussion you can see both our arguments for and against it. Read the discussion and inform your own opinion.
I would even go further by saying that your application components shouldn't depend on IHttpContextAccessor anyway, because it couples them to HttpContext. They should instead depend on application-tailored abstractions. Inside your application's startup path, you can have adapter implementations for those application-tailored abstractions that take a dependency on HttpContextAccessor.

This great explanation should be put in Microsoft doc instead of the vague "This interface should be used with caution."

Many thanks. That's a great explanation of why it shouldn't be used, but doesn't answer the part of the question about what I should do instead? I have added my service that injects HttpContext.User.Identity.Name into a consuming service. Basically I need the authenticated user in the db, and none of the existing code is passing it at the moment.

One alternative for injecting IHttpContextAccessor is to inject HttpContext directly into consumers.

Steven's answer is very good and probably technically more correct that this one, but this one will try to explain why you shouldn't use IHttpContextAccessor in terms of scoping and what you should do instead.
The implementation of IHttpContextAccessor is a Singleton. It is not in the Scope of your request and therefore when it actually tries to grab your HttpContext info it has to do all kind of jiggerypokery under the hood in terms of locks etc to grab the info for your request and scope. From what I understand from Steven's answer, this can slow performance app wide and also sometimes it can grab the wrong info/not get the info (not sure which). Conclusion: never use IHttpContextAccessor.
As Steven says above, you can simply inject HttpContext directly into your services. That's fine, but creates a dependency on httpContext that you probably don't want or need. In my case, I just want the user identity, so I created a UserContext class with one property UserName and an Interface IUserContext. services.AddScoped<IUserContext, UserContext>(); in the DI setup. And then populate it from HttpContext in middleware (after authentication). Then inject the IUserContext into services.

"it can grab the wrong info/not get the info (not sure which)". The latter one: it can return null after asynchronously iterating over an enumerable. It will never return the wrong info, although returning nothing is almost as bad.

I used to use HttpContextAccessor in my service class (CurrentUserService) where I would check for the currently authenticated user's details. But since HttpContextAccessor is not recommended any more, I inject my CurrentUserService to DI as scoped and then using middleware set the User (ClaimsPrincipal). Something like this:
public class CurrentUserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager)
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal? User { get; set; }  // Will be set via inline middleware

    public bool IsAuthenticated() => User is not null && User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true;

    public string? GetUserId() => IsAuthenticated() ? _userManager.GetUserId(User) : null;

    public async Task<ApplicationUser?> GetUserAsync() => IsAuthenticated() ? await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User) : null;
}

And then in Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddScoped<CurrentUserService>();    
.
.
.
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Set the ClaimsPrincipal user in service
    context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<CurrentUserService>().User = context.User;
    await next();
});

